# SQL query according to parameter passed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a condition, where if the parameter passed is US then I want the input_value to be
"Hours Calculated", if it is CA then I want it to be "HRS" and "Hours" and if I do not pass anything then all three should be picked.

```
Select element_name
from element_tab JOIN
INPUTVAL_TAB
where ELEMENT_TAB.LEGISLATION_CODE = nvl(:P_LC,ELEMENT_TAB.LEGISLATION_CODE)
AND INPUTVAL_TAB.INPUT_ID = ELEMENT_TAB.INPUT_ID
AND INPUTVAL_TAB.BASE_NAME = DECODE(:p_LC,'US','Hours Calculated','CA','HRS','CA','Hours')
```

How can the above query be changed so that if i do not pass :p_LC parameter then 'Hours Calculated','HRS'
and 'Hours', all three are picked?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a null value:

```
AND (
     (:p_LC IS NULL
      AND INPUTVAL_TAB.BASE_NAME IN ('Hours Calculated', 'HRS', 'Hours'))
  OR (:p_LC IS NOT NULL
      AND INPUTVAL_TAB.BASE_NAME = DECODE(:p_LC,'US','Hours Calculated','CA','HRS','CA','Hours'))
)
```

It might be clearer, for someone maintaining this in the future, to do:

```
AND (
     (:p_LC IS NULL AND INPUTVAL_TAB.BASE_NAME IN ('Hours Calculated', 'HRS', 'Hours'))
  OR (:p_LC = 'US' AND INPUTVAL_TAB.BASE_NAME = 'Hours Calculated')
  OR (:p_LC = 'CA' AND INPUTVAL_TAB.BASE_NAME IN ('HRS', 'Hours'))
)
```

---

> I have already used NVL to check the :p_lc null value

Not relevant, but personally'd I'd prefer to do the first check the same way; so rather than:

```
where ELEMENT_TAB.LEGISLATION_CODE = nvl(:P_LC,ELEMENT_TAB.LEGISLATION_CODE)
```

I would do:

```
where (
  :p_LC IS NULL
  OR ELEMENT_TAB.LEGISLATION_CODE = :p_LC
)
```

... but that's largely a matter of taste.

Comment: IF :P_LC IS NULL I want all three base_names to be passed ('HRS', 'Hours' and 'Hours Calculated' ), the above query is not doing that...

Comment: I have already used NVL to check the :p_lc null value...

Comment: Are there other values than 'HRS', 'Hours' and 'Hours Calculated' ?

Comment: @SHSH_123 - OK, I read the question as not filtering that at all. Are there others? I've updated to only look for those three.

Comment: @AlexPoole  - I think the updated one would work.. just checking that and will confirm !

Comment: @AlexPoole - This is working but processing time is too much

Comment: @SHSH_123 - I'd missed some closing parentheses when I updated it before; it wouldn't have run without them, so presumably you added them, hopefully in the right places! If those are right then you'll need to look at the execution plan and see how this has changed it, I would expect Oracle to be clever enough to still use appropriate indexes but the plan will tell you if it isn't.